# Loading GeoJSON by AJAX method in OpenLayers, centering the map automatically

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geojson

I'm trying to center the map on the geometries that are on the map. To encompass all but until now I have not succeeded in how ...

It centers further than geometries :(

```
  if (ol.proj.proj4 && ol.proj.proj4.register) { ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); }

var features;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_geojson.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
       features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
    }
});

  features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setId(undefined);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: features
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions:
                ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
        }).extend([
            new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
            new ol.control.FullScreen(),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()

        ]),
        interactions: [
            new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.DragPan(),
            new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom()
        ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([698282.236, 377375.758], 'EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14,
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to build an extent from the geometries and fit the view to that

```
  var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
  features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setId(undefined);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
    ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: features
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions:
                ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
        }).extend([
            new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
            new ol.control.FullScreen(),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()

        ]),
        interactions: [
            new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.DragPan(),
            new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom()
        ],
    view: new ol.View()
  });
  map.getView().fit(extent);
```